# Is the set of totally ordered sets totally ordered?

Tags: order-theory

This seems super intuitive, but I can't seem to prove it.
Is the set of equivalence classes of totally ordered sets totally ordered?

More precisely, given two totally ordered sets, $F$ and $G$, does there always exist an order preserving injection from one into the other?

I would think there is some adaptation of Zermelo's theorem that can fix the problem, but again, I can't seem to find it.

Comment: It's true for well-orders, that's what ordinal numbers are for. Not for general orders. We do know that all countable orders order-embed into $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Note that the set of totally ordered sets does not exist, as the totally ordered sets form a proper class. The formulation in your second paragraph is free of that problem, as it only talks about two arbitrary totally ordered sets, not about the set of all of them.

Comment: @celtschk: If you want to get technical, then each equivalence class is also a proper class... So actually the class of equivalence classes does not exist. Of course we can circumvent this by defining some sort of "Scott representatives" using Scott's trick, or by some other way (e.g. restricting the underlying set to be an ordinal) or by simply considering the pre-order, rather than the quotient order.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The natural numbers, $\omega$ and their inverse order (i.e. the negative integers) are incomparable.

But this is not even a partial order. The rational numbers embed into $[0,1]\cap\Bbb Q$ and vice versa, so it's not even antisymmetric.

Comment: I feel the downvote may have been due to the fact that I didn't remove the HNQ status from a question that I answered. I would have done that sooner, but sometimes I too like to close my eyes for a few hours.

Comment: What is the HNQ status? Just wondering.

Comment: Hot Network Questions, it means high exposure to the question and usually plenty of votes to the answerers.

Comment: Oh, right. That solves it. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

The answer is no, for example there is no order preserving injection $\omega_1\to\Bbb R$ (every ordinal embedding into the reals is countable) as well as no order preserving injection $\Bbb R\to\omega_1$ (since $\Bbb R$ has infinite descending chains, while $\omega_1$ doesn't)

Comment: Why are you working so hard? The natural numbers and their inverse...

Comment: Fair enough, I went for the first example that came to my mind rather than the simplest one @AsafKaragila

Comment: The simplest way to fix this is to train your mind to go to the simplest example first! :-)